# transfering data from the s3 to s3 glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

How do I transfer my s3 buckets to the s3 glacier for cost reduction.
I have buckets with TB of data that is frequently not used, but want all that data to be stored in some cost reduction platform so that I can access the data very rarely. I have seen that s3 glacier is less cost comparing to the s3 storage.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple **storage classes** available in Amazon S3. Details are available at: [Amazon S3 Simple Storage Service Pricing - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

- **S3 Standard** storage (2.3c/GB) is replicated across the region and is instantly available
- **S3 Standard - Infrequent Access** (1.25c/GB) is replicated across the region, is instantly available and has a lower storage cost, but **there is a charge for accessing data**. This storage class is worthwhile if the data is accessed less than once per month.
- **S3 One Zone - Infrequent Access** (1c/GB) is the same, but is only stored in one Availability Zone so has less durability. Make sure you have another copy of the data elsewhere in case of (very rare) failure. Great for backups.
- **S3 Glacier** (0.4c/GB) is replicated across the region and has a very low storage cost, but there is a charge for retrieving data. The charge is higher if you want the data back quickly. Great for content you rarely need and would be willing to wait a while to retrieve it (max 12 hours).
- **S3 Glacier Deep Archive** (0.01c/GB) is replicated across the region and is ultra-low cost, but it takes
  longer to retrieve data (up to 48 hours).

See: [Amazon S3 Glacier and S3 Glacier Deep Archive - AWS Prescriptive Guidance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/backup-recovery/amazon-s3-glacier.html)

The easiest way to **transition objects to S3 Glacier** or other storage classes is to use [Object lifecycle management - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev-retired/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html). Just give it some rules (eg which folder) and it will transition the data. **This does incur costs**, so make sure you understand the [Amazon S3 Simple Storage Service Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/).